# Search not working?

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I load https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=topology (or any other search query) I get a **Your search returned no matches.** response.

Comment: Could someone check whether they seem the same problem and report here?

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: Okay, I've pinged SE.

Comment: Indeed. This only seems to be for the basic text search. Various other filters are working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be working now. Upgrading our search clusters today, and so things might be a bit off here an there.